# Backup complete iPhone AddressBook programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I need to backup all contacts with all records (numbers, names, image, ...) programmatically. I read about the AddressBook.framework, but is there an easy way to make a backup all contacts?

Comment: Yeah. Connect your iPhone to iTunes and back it up. Any particular reason why you'd need a user's *entire* database of contacts? There have been some major apps who have gotten in trouble for this in the recent past.

Comment: it's necessary for my app idea... the data will only be stored local. why should that be a problem?

Answer (score 6):

1.One way of doing this is to create a vCard string with all your contacts. Like this:

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
CFArrayRef peopleForBackup  = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
CFDataRef vcards = (CFDataRef)ABPersonCreateVCardRepresentationWithPeople(peopleForBackup);
vcardString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:(NSData *)vcards encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

And write this string to a file for backup.

2.Delete current contacts from address book:

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
CFArrayRef people = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
int arrayCount = CFArrayGetCount(people);
ABRecordRef abrecord;

for (int i = 0; i < arrayCount; i++) {
    abrecord = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(people, i);
    ABAddressBookRemoveRecord(addressBook,abrecord, NULL);
}
CFRelease(people);
```

3.To restore from the backup you just read the vcard file into a string and itterate through the person-records in the vcard and add them as records to an addressbook, then save it.

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
NSData *stringData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:contactFilePath];
NSString *vcardFromFile = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:stringData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

CFDataRef vCardData = (CFDataRef)[vcardFromFile dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

ABRecordRef defaultSource = ABAddressBookCopyDefaultSource(addressBook);
CFArrayRef vCardPeople = ABPersonCreatePeopleInSourceWithVCardRepresentation(defaultSource, vCardData);

for (CFIndex index = 0; index < CFArrayGetCount(vCardPeople); index++) {
    ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(vCardPeople, index);
    ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBook, person, NULL);
    CFRelease(person);
}

CFRelease(vCardPeople);
CFRelease(defaultSource);
bool success = ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, NULL);
```

A Problem with this approach is that I dont know of a way to maintain the linking of contacts (exchange, facebook...).

Answer (score 0):

It depends what properties of the contacts you want to backup. If you want to backup their first names and last names, do something like this:

```
//CREATE ARRAYS STORING FIRST NAMES AND LAST NAMES
NSMutableArray *firstNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *lastNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
NSArray *arrayOfPeople = (__bridge_transfer NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
CFRelease(addressBook);

for(NSUInteger index = 0; index <= ([arrayOfPeople count]-1); index++){

    ABRecordRef currentPerson = (__bridge ABRecordRef)[arrayOfPeople objectAtIndex: index];
    [firstNames addObject: (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(currentPerson, kABPersonFirstNameProperty)];
    [lastNames addObject: (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(currentPerson, kABPersonLastNameProperty)];        
}

//BACKUP THE ARRAYS IN A PLIST 
NSArray *array=[NSArray arrayWithObjects: firstNames, lastNames, nil];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *location = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingString:@"/somefilename.plist"];
[array writeToFile:location atomically:YES];
```

If you have any questions about the code, just ask in the comments. Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the code! but i want to backup ALL entrys of a contact... i thougt there is maybe a function that simply make a dump of the entire adressbook.

Comment: @Boeringer I looked through the class references of the classes in the Address Book framework and it looks like there's not a function to do this. You could, however, create an NSMutableArray for each entry of a contact, but this would be tedious.